# How to remove Validation Display Error box shown on top in wpf?

Tags: wpf, validation, user-controls

In my wpf user control, I have a text box with an error validation box. and it works fine. but when I reduce screen size, the error box comes top to next panel aside the text box, when the text box and other controls go down of the panel. How to make it working fine?

Here is the xaml code:

```
        <UserControl.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="DefaultUser"
                     UriSource="/Capstone_ERP;component/Images/default-user-image.jpg" />
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="LeftErrorTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).[0].ErrorContent, ElementName=ErrorAdorner}"
                           Foreground="#FFB83F3F"
                           TextAlignment="Right"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           FontFamily="Arial"
                           FontSize="11" />
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="ErrorAdorner">
                    <Border BorderBrush="LightCoral"
                            BorderThickness="1" />
                </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="27" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="165" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="24,24,0,0"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="Name :"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Height="24"
                   Width="123" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="24,70,0,0"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="Address :"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Height="20"
                   Width="123" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="24,176,0,0"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="Contact No :"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Height="20"
                   Width="123" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="24,218,0,0"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="E-mail :"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Height="20"
                   Width="123" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="24,260,0,0"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="User Roll :"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   RenderTransformOrigin="1.793,-1.754"
                   Height="20"
                   Width="123" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                 Height="23"
                 Margin="9,22,0,0"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                 Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource LeftErrorTemplate}"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Width="418" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                 Height="91"
                 Margin="10,60,0,0"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 Text="{Binding Address, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                 Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource LeftErrorTemplate}"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Width="418"
                 AcceptsReturn="True"
                 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                 Height="23"
                 Margin="9,173,0,0"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 Text="{Binding ContactNo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                 Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource LeftErrorTemplate}"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Width="417" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                 Height="24"
                 Margin="10,215,0,0"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 Text="{Binding Email, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                 Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource LeftErrorTemplate}"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Width="417" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"
                  Margin="9,254,0,0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Height="22"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding UserRollColloction,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUserRoll}"
                  SelectedValuePath="Value"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Display"
                  Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource LeftErrorTemplate}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Width="417" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: need to show you XAML for the user control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the XAML it looks as if you have forgotten to add a row to the grid for each input field. So you 'name' text block needs to be in Grid.Row = 0 and then your 'address' text block needs to be Grid.Row = 1 and so forth for each fields. Do the same for your TextBox and ComboBox control, so they are each of a different Grid.Row. Then you need to add some extra entries in your Grid.RowDefinitions so the number of RowDefinition entries matches the number you need for display.